# How do I fade background images using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, background, mouseover, fade

I want to have the background image change form one to another and fade in the process. Consider this for a mouseover/mouseout situation.

How do I fade background images using jQuery?

Is there a jQuery plugin that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be something available, but it should be easy to put together from the following parts:

- Use the [hover pseudo event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) to check when the mouse enters and leaves an element.
- Use [`fadeIn`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn#speedcallback) and [`fadeOut`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut#speedcallback) to change the opacity of an element.
- Create a div with `position:absolute` and put two images inside it with `position:relative`. This will make the images stack on top of each other

Comment: You mean download both images at once and hide one initially?

Comment: Yup, unless they are really big.