# fade cycle an array of images in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of background images that I would like to cycle through as a simple fade effect. This is easily done with the image html tag but i need them to be background images set as a style. The background images are dynamically pulled through using a cms.

Here is the link so you can see what I'm dealing with on the homepage (the current image is just a background image set in css n the page-top div):

[link](http://conceptfiresec.limegreentangerine.net)

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fade background images using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966912/how-do-i-fade-background-images-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect can be easily achieved by [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) jquery plugin:

an example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pics"> 
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="normal height" height="normal height" /> 
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" width="normal height" height="normal height" /> 
    <img src="images/image3.jpg" width="normal height" height="normal height" /> 
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".pics").cycle({
   ,options,
});
```

you should set your pics `div` width and height the same as the width and height of the page and with **hidden overflow** to prevent image being overflown.

here is a sample:h[ttp://bazar-restaurant.somee.com](http://bazar-restaurant.somee.com)